# Add margin only at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a cookie section that is always fixed at the bottom of the view.

```
<section id="cookie-section">
    <span id="cookie-text">Bla bla bla</span>
</section>

#cookie-section {
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.9);
}
```

But when you scroll and reach the bottom of the page I want to add a margin-bottom of 50px to it. How do I do it?

When you just add `margin-bottom: 50px;` to it, it already gets the margin at the start which I don't want. Only when you reach the bottom of the page with scrolling.

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need javascript

Answer (score 1):

Doable with [scroll driven animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_scroll-driven_animations) but the support is not good yet.

You can test the below using Google Chrome

```css
#cookie-section {
  min-height: 50px;
  inset: auto 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  animation: margin 2s;
  animation-timeline: scroll(root); /* consider the root scroll */
  animation-range-start: 90%; /* start the animation when you reach the last 10% of the scroll */ 
}

@keyframes margin {
  to {margin-bottom:50px;}
}

body {
  min-height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="cookie-section">
  <span id="cookie-text">Bla bla bla</span>
</section>
```